# Rectangle inscribed in a triangle

Tags: geometry

How can I prove that the geometric location of the center of the rectangle MNPQ (M, N on BC, P on CA, Q on AB) inscribed in the triangle ABC is the segment connecting BC and the midpoint of the altitude belonging to A in any given triangle.
I made an animation of this using geogebra but i don't know how i could prove this mathematically,because from the animation we can see clearly that this is true but i dont know how to write it down.I appreciate any tips or help!

Here is a link to the animation:

https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/qwdv32ex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the axes formed by the triangle $ABC$, $B(0, 0)$, $C(1, 0)$, $A(0, 1)$ and $I(a, 0)$ the point in $[BC]$ where $(AI)$ is the height of $ABC$.
Let $M(t, 0)$. We have $t \in [0,a]$ because $M \in [B, I]$.

1. By Thalès :
   $$\dfrac{BM}{BI} = \dfrac{BQ}{BA}$$
   then :
   $$BQ = \dfrac{BM}{BI} BA = \dfrac{t}{a}$$
   Hence $Q\left(0, \dfrac{t}{a}\right)$.
2. $P$ and $Q$ have the same $y$ and $P$ belong to the line of equation $x + y = 1$ then $P\left(1 - \dfrac{t}{a}, \dfrac{t}{a}\right)$.

We deduce that the center $O$ of the rectangle $MNPQ$ wich is the midpoint of $[PM]$ has the coordinate :
$$O \left(\dfrac{t + 1 - \dfrac{t}{a}}{2}, \dfrac{t}{2a}\right) = \left(\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{a - 1}{2 a} t, \dfrac{t}{2a}\right)$$  
Wich means that $O$ belong to the segment of represetation :
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
x & = & \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{a - 1}{2 a} t \\[3mm]
y & = & \dfrac{t}{2a}
\end{array} \right. (t \in [0, a])$$
When $t = 0$ (M = B) we have $O \left(\dfrac{1}{2}, 0\right)$. It's the midpoint of $[BC]$.
When $t = a$ ($M = I$) we have $O \left(\dfrac{a}{2}, \dfrac{1}{2}\right)$. It's the midpoint of $[AI]$.